# html how to update video src url's parameter without affect the playing video?

Tags: javascript, html, web, video

I have video hosted on cdn, and protected by the access control with timestamp sign parameter like below url

```
http://example.com/xxx.mp4?sign=bac9f2b32330d79d97c7022f2518&t=61df9fc7
```

When the video is very long, the sign will expired. So I need to update the sign.

So I change the sign every time before it expire and change the video's src. But it will lead the video stop play and back to the begin.

Comment: Do you have to pass the `sign` through URL params? Sounds like a cookie would be more appropriate. One solution would be to use the [MSE API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), but the format of the video you can pass is quite restrictive, an other *solution* would be to fetch the entirety of the video and display that, but for "very long" videos that means very big files in memory.

Comment: Yes, I cannot change the `sign` from URL parameters to cookie. The access control service as provided by the CDN provider.

Comment: What about saving the video's `currentTime` when the HTTP error causes the video's `error` event? The video's URL can be changed, await the `loadstart` event, and set `currentTime` to its pre-error value.